# Erro a exibir/ocultar Div com Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Necessito ocultar campos usando `Angular JS`, após clicar um botão será exibido a `label` abaixo:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<div>
    <input type="button" ng-model="btnArea" ng-init="btnArea = true" value="Áreas">
    <input type="button" ng-model="btnPonto" ng-init="btnPonto = true" value="Pontos">
</div>

<div ng-if="btnArea">
    <h1>Áreas</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my Áreas.</p>
    <hr>
</div>

<div ng-if="btnPonto">
    <h1>Pontos</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my Pontos.</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Link: [JSEddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexjosesilva/dyhbqhnm/6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer um evento aliado a diretiva `ngClick`, que irá detectar o click no elemento, veja o exemplo:

```
ng-click="btnArea = !btnArea; btnPonto = false"
ng-click="btnPonto = !btnPonto; btnArea = false"

<input type="button" ng-model="btnArea"  ng-click="btnArea = !btnArea; btnPonto = false" value="Áreas">
<input type="button" ng-model="btnPonto" ng-click="btnPonto = !btnPonto; btnArea = false" value="Pontos">
```

Isso vai criar um evento de "toggle" alternando o valor entre `true` e `false` a cada click. A segunda parte do `ngClick` irá apenas deixar o valor do outro elemento como `false`, assim ele será escondido quando o outro for exibido.

---

Simplificando o seu código, como você deseja iniciar a exibição com as `divs` escondidas, seu código ficaria assim:

```
<div>
   <input type="button" ng-model="btnArea"  ng-click="btnArea = !btnArea; btnPonto = false"   value="Áreas">
   <input type="button" ng-model="btnPonto" ng-click="btnPonto = !btnPonto; btnArea = false" value="Pontos">
</div>

<div ng-if="btnArea">[...]</div>
<div ng-if="btnPonto">[...]</div>
```

[Veja seu exemplo atualizado](https://jsfiddle.net/dyhbqhnm/12/).

Comment: Como ocultar o outro campo ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva então, cada botão tem o seu `ng-click` que controla a exibição da div correspondente.

Comment: acontece que é exibido os dois campos ao mesmo tempo...

Comment: Acontece que no exemplo esta sendo exibido os dois ao mesmo tempo...

Comment: @alexjosesilva Mas o que você deseja fazer? exibir apenas um ou outro?

Comment: A ideia inicial é exibir apenas o campo apos clicar o botão e ocultar outro campo...algum dica @celsomtrindade

Comment: @alexjosesilva atualizei minha resposta, veja se é isso que busca.